# Less css - Id with variable, google plus, cover all

Tags: css, variables, less, google-plus

I want to be able to style google plus share button. The problem is that I dynamically add and removes it on a single page. Every time I add it, the api adds +1 to the id of the button. Like:

```
#___plus_0
#___plus_1
#___plus_2
    ...
#___plus_10
```

I use less css, is it possible to cover all these id´s with one command? I have tried with:

```
#___plus_*
```

But that doesn't work.

I could do it like,

```
#___plus_0, #___plus_1, #___plus_2, #___plus_1, #___plus_4,...,#___plus_20
```

But that seems a little hacky and it would break if the user for some reason decides to remove and re add the share button 20 times.

If this isn't possible, is it possible to tell google what Id it should set on the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS3 you can achieve this with [substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings). You could write something like this:

```
[id^="___plus_"]{ ... }
```

if you want to select all elements with an `id` that starts with `___plus_`.
However, this may have some problems [in some older browsers](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/).